# Setting the GAE app version from a computer property in Maven

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-3

I'd like to derive the version for my AppEngine Standard app from the POM's version, by using the `maven-build-helper-plugin` `regex-property` goal to turn the Maven POM version in a valid GAE version string (lowercase, only alphanumeric chars and underline).

So in the POM I'm trying to do this:

```
<groupId>foobar.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>version-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compute-gae-version</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>regex-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>gae.version</name>
                        <regex>[^A-Za-z0-9]+</regex>
                        <value>${project.version}</value>
                        <replacement>-</replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                        <toLowerCase>true</toLowerCase>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <deploy.version>${gae.version}</deploy.version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
     [...]
</dependencies>
```

Except of course it does not work: the App gets deployed with the default  timestamp-computed version label. I understand this is because the `configuration` block for the AppEngine plugin gets evaluated early, before build-helper runs.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the same issue as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149139/build-helper-maven-plugin-unable-to-use-replaced-value-with-other-plugins) post.

Move the configuration block out of the executions block, and use `mvn build-helper:regex-property appengine:deploy` to deploy the GAE app version, as suggested by fboulay.